# Naming convention issue for HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models in a HABTM relationship: `MaintenanceOrder` and `Maintenance`. The migration was declared as below

```
create_table :maintenance_orders do |t|
  ...
end
create_table :maintenances do |t|
  ...
end
```

With regards to creating the join table, I noticed that if I have:

```
create_table :maintenances_maintenance_orders, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :maintenance, index: true
  t.belongs_to :maintenance_order, index: true
end
```

Then I will get an error:

```
I have two models that are similar, and I'm wondering if this is the cause of the error?

@maintenance.maintenances
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'maintenance_orders_maintenances'
@maintenance_order.maintenances
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'maintenance_orders_maintenances'
```

Whereas if I have, as the error suggests a join table like this:

```
create_table :maintenance_orders_maintenances, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :maintenance_order, index: true
  t.belongs_to :maintenance, index: true
end
```

It all works fine. But I'm asking this question because as far as I understand, by definition of a HABTM, what order the models are declared shouldn't matter. So... is this just because the names are so similar and there's a snake case that I need to do it in this way (like maybe having `maintenances_maintenance` is SUPER confusing) or...? Any rules on this?

Comment: By default, Rails orders table names in alphabetic order. `maintenance_order` comes before `maintenances` so `:maintenance_orders_maintenances` is what rails will expect the table to be named

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rails orders table names in alphabetic order in a join-table name. `maintenance_order` comes before `maintenances` so `:maintenance_orders_maintenances` is what rails will expect the table to be named. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table for details.

If you depart from what Rails expects, you can configure the table-name yourself, but it's better to follow the standard naming procedure.

Note that it's well worth your time reading through all the Rails Guides - you'll level up your rails knowledge quite nicely that way.